# Unable to create table from model with sqlalchemy and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do my first database migration with [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database). The difference is that the writer start from scratch whereas I already have a MySQL database.

Yet, as the writer did in his tutorial, I wrote the new database models in`app/models.py`:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

It will include the users table that maps to the User database model of a Flask application.

I was worried that the database migration script was empty and that the flask  db migrate commands didn't seemed to create a database. I therfore tried to play with it using the interpreter :

```
>>> from app import db
>>> from app.models import User, Post
>>> u = User(username='john', email='john@example.com')
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 943, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
...
...
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user (username, email, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('john', 'john@example.com', None)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
...
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
...
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user (username, email, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('john', 'john@example.com', None)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

How can I create my database and deal with this problem then ?

Here is my `config.py` file

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    # ...
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

Comment: Have you defined your DB connection URL properly? You'd seem to be using SQLite, yet you mention having an existing MySQL db.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm not sure ! I'm going to add my `config.py` file

Comment: It seems your configuration defaults to an SQLite DB, so have you at any point called [`db.create_all()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) while using that?

Comment: @IljaEverilä, No I don't think so, I haven't found it in [the tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)

Answer (score 0):

I had to code `db.create_all()` in the command line as said Mr Everilä, even if it wasn't written in the tutorial